# How to repeat image in img tag (not a CSS background image)

Tags: html, css

On my page, I have a logo in the upper left corner with a repeating image creating a banner extending over the the right of the page.  They work nicely using background images.

```
.logo {
    background: white url('img/logo-sml.png') center no-repeat;
    width: 81px; height: 62px;
    outline: 7px solid #D15F08;
    padding: 8px 2px;
    position: absolute; top: 15px; left: 15px;
}
.topstripe {
    background: transparent url('img/bg_top.png') repeat-x scroll 0 0;
    height: 39px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Many of my visitors like to print the pages, and I would like the logo and stripe to appear when printing.  I have read pages that discuss a separate CSS page for printing.  Where I have a repeating image, is this my only option, or is there a way to get an image in an IMG tag to repeat?

i.e. something like:

```
<img src="img/bg_top.png" style:"display: repeat-x"/>
```

But in a way that will print.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. But you can display a repeating background image only on print by using media queries: `@media print { /* CSS here */ }`.

Comment: When I looked at other answers using `@media print`, it appeared that the goal was to create a dumby that was invisible normally, but then became visible when printing.  In such a case, the repeat-x still causes a problem, right?  Or does that tag force it to print, so I just repeat the same CSS, but now within the tag?

Comment: Sorry, ignore my last comment. Using `@media print` will not force the browser to print background images. When that's said, what does your repeating background/stripe look like? Will you be able to simply stretch the image to a width of `100%`?

Comment: It has a pattern that would need to be repeated, so a stretch would not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is possible.  What I did, to solve my need, was to leave my image in the top banner per the CSS above, but then added an `@media print` attribute that was "close enough" for the print versions:

```
.printtopstripe { visibility: hidden; }
@media print {
    .topstripe {
        background: none;
        height: 15px;
    }
    .printtopstripe { visibility:visible; height:17px; width:100%; }
}
```

If somebody comes up with a better solution, please post it, I am happy to change my solution and choose theirs.

Comment: I'm not sure who downvoted this, but why don't you offer something helpful, an answer or comment or something.  The goal is to help people solve problems and a valid question with only one answer clearly needs some help.